# Location Services in Mac

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, core-location

I have built an application which uses location services in Mac. When i install this app, the application appears in the Location Services list (System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Location Services.

When i uninstall the app, the entry does not go away from the list. However, when i click the entry, it disappears.

I know that this entry can be removed by manipulating the `/private/var/db/locationd/clients.plist` file.

I noticed the same behaviour with few other applications. What I want to know is, whether this is intended behaviour? Or should i specifically take care of removing this entry from clients.plist during uninstallation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a known issue in 10.7 and 10.8, but should be fixed in 10.9. For your app, you probably shouldn't worry about it. Manually tweaking `clients.plist` requires root and is a lot of work just to prevent an entry in a prefpane most people rarely use.

Your users can follow the guide at https://superuser.com/questions/526183/remove-applications-from-location-services-in-security-privacy-on-mac-os-x-10 if they really want to get rid of them.